# Android Database Connection using jdbc or anything similar

Tags: php, android, mysql, workbench

I am fairly new in android programming ...
I have created an android app that lets me connect to a remote database using php and mysql.
I want to know if there's a way to connect to the database using jdbc and mysql workbench keeping the CRUD(Create , Read , Update , Delete) options in the client-side itself and not using server-side languages such as php.

Also if this is the best way to go forward...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not possible for now to use such things in android side.and if you have remote database then you can access it via HttpRequests with WebServices.
for locally data storage you can use SQLite as it does not require any drivers etc or your can do File Based storage.

Comment: exactly :-) use sqllite

Comment: Can SQLite be used as a remote database ?

Comment: no it cant be used as remote database its local fileBased database.

Comment: so the best way for accessing a remote database is through a web service ?

Answer (score 0):

check this, it is possible to achieve

http://capdroid.wordpress.com/2012/07/10/configuring-and-accessing-mysql-jdbc-driver-on-android-application/

http://www.aceql.com/why-secure-jdbc-over-http-for-android-swing-javafx.html

Comment: its just kind of hack and we cant use such things in production